# Sign of a function near the boundary

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^N$, $N \geq 2$, be a smooth bounded open set. Let $f \in C^1(\overline \Omega)$, and suppose that
$$
f = 0, \quad \frac{\partial f}{\partial \nu} < 0 \qquad \text{on } \quad \partial \Omega,
$$
where $\nu$ is the outer unit normal vector to $\partial \Omega$.

It is very intuitive that $f > 0$ in an $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $\partial \Omega$, that is, $f > 0$ in the set
$$
A_\varepsilon := \{x \in \Omega \ : \ d(x, \partial \Omega) < \varepsilon\}
$$
for some $\varepsilon > 0$. Nonetheless, I am failing to obtain a proof with sufficient details to really convince me.

My attempt begins with taking a neighborhood of each point $x \in \partial \Omega$ where $f > 0$ and then using the compactness of $\overline \Omega$ to find the neighborhood I want. The compactness part is OK, but the beginning is kind of tricky to me.

Any suggestions on how to start?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In this kind of proof, I think you typically start by handling the case $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^{N-1} \times \mathbb{R}_+$ so that $\nu = - e_N$. Then it is clear that $f > 0$ in a neighborhood of $ x= 0$. And the case of smooth domain reduces to the half-space by a local change of coordinates.

Comment: @cs89 thanks for the comment, but can you be more precise on how it would help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be a $C^1$ bounded open set. The $C^1$ regularity means that, for every $x_0 \in \partial\Omega$, there exists an open ball $B \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ with center $x_0$ and a one-to-one map $\psi : B \to D \subset \mathbb{R}^{N}$ such that:

- $\psi(x_0) = 0$,
- $\psi(B \cap \Omega) \subset \mathbb{R}^{N-1} \times \mathbb{R}_+$,
- $\psi(B \cap \partial\Omega) \subset \mathbb{R}^{N-1} \times \{ 0 \}$,
- $\psi \in C^1(B,D)$ and $\psi^{-1} \in C^1(D,B)$.

Now take an $x_0 \in \partial \Omega$, such a ball $B$ and local chart $\psi$. Define $g := f\circ \psi^{-1}$ on a neighborhood of $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^{N-1} \times \mathbb{R}_+$. For example, $g$ is well defined on $\{ y \in \mathbb{R}^N ; |y| \leq \delta, y_N \geq 0 \}$. Since $f$ vanishes on $\partial \Omega$, $g = 0$ on $\{ y \in \mathbb{R}^N ; |y| \leq \delta, y_N = 0 \}$.

Moreover
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_N}(y) = \frac{\partial \psi^{-1}}{\partial y_N}(y) \nabla f(\psi^{-1}(y)).
$$
Since $\frac{\partial \psi^{-1}}{\partial x_N}(0)$ is colinear to $-\nu(x_0)$, you have, as $y \to 0$,
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial y_N}(y) \to - c \frac{\partial f}{\partial \nu}(x_0)
$$
and in particular $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y_N}(y) > 0$ for $y$ close enough from $0$. From this you deduce that $g > 0$ in $\{ y \in \mathbb{R}^N ; |y| \leq \delta', y_N > 0 \}$ for some small enough $\delta' > 0$.
Writing $f = g \circ \psi$, you obtain that there is indeed a small neighborhood of $x_0$ (within $\Omega$) where $f > 0$.

From there, you can plug your compactness argument.

Comment: Thank you very much. So the idea is to pass to the flat boundary in order to make the problem unidimensional and then to use classical results for a function in $\mathbb R$, is that correct?

Comment: Yes. For the particular case you have in mind, maybe there is a more clever and shorter proof. But I wanted to showcase the general more robust approach.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is very clear now.